Upper bound of a difference
Given a function V such that:
$V(z)<V(-z) \forall{z>0}$ and
$V'(0)\ne 0 \ \ exists$,
we have that if $E[V(Yf(X))|X=x]$ has a global minimizer $\hat{f(x)}$ and $p(x)\ne0.5$, then $sgn(\hat{f(x)})=sgn(p(x)-0.5)$
Let $A(z)=p(x)V(z)+[1-p(x)]V(-z)$, it's easy to check that $E[V(Yf(X))|X=x]=A(f(x))$, so $\hat{f(x)}$ minimizes A.
We have $A'(0)=p(x)V'(0)-[1-p(x)]V'(0)=[2p(x)-1]V'(0)\ne 0$ because $V'(0)\ne0$ exists and $p(x)\ne 0.5$ (proven previously), thus $0$ is not a minimizer of A.
Since $\hat{f(x)}$ is a global minimizer of A, we have
$0\ge A(\hat{f(x)})-A(-\hat{f(x)})$
Why $0$ is an upper bound of the difference?
